# Flash Builder Burrito alternatives?

Tags: android, flash, ide, air

are there any alternatives for the Flash Builder Burrito IDE for mobile development based on the flash technology?

Thank you very much for any information,
Cyril

Comment: Good question. Out of curiosity, why do you ask? Are you after a better interface? cheaper software? just wondering?

Comment: actually, I am just writing an article about flash burrito ide, and I want to know alternatives for this ide. Thanks for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Develop (www.flashdevelop.org) - free and open source (MIT license)

Comment: Can Flash Develop use the Hero SDK and work like FB Burrito though?

Comment: Thanks Tony! I will try to create a mobile app with Flash Develop.